# Should an ObjectContext in a static method be disposed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, static

Just a quick sanity check here!

If I have a static method in an instance class e.g:

```
public class myClass 
{

    public static void AMethod() 
    {
        //do somit
    }

}
```

Would it cause problems if I was making reference to IDisposable resources in the method body, an object context for example?

```
    public static void AMethod() 
    {
        ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext();

        // do somit
    }
```

By would it cause problems, I mean, would it retain the object context behind the scenes after the end of the method body due to the fact it was a static method?

The class as can be seen, isn't static, and the variable is local to the method.

I'm aware that I should be using 'using' here, just curious as to whether this particular combo of events could/would cause memory leaks.

Comment: This link says don't do it - good article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/07/tip-18-how-to-decide-on-a-lifetime-for-your-objectcontext.aspx

Comment: Do you have a [Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8(v=vs.80).aspx) background, perhaps? There's nothing special about variables declared inside of static methods.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't no, just curious as from my understanding if the property was static and therefore the class that the reference would exist for the duration of the application instance.

Comment: Even in languages that support static *variables* (e.g. VB as mentioned, C++), the variables themselves have to be decorated with `static` to achieve lifetimes longer than scope.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that was my understanding, just wanted to check the static modifier on the method would display any similar behaviours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid any problems it is recommended to dispose IDisposable resources as soon as you have finished using them. This could happen by wrapping them in a `using` statement:

```
public static void AMethod() 
{
    using (ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext())
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: These were my thoughts, just wondered whether the static method would retain any reference to the resource after perhaps the class instance itself was GC'd

Comment: @dougajmcdonald, after leaving the static method, any local variables are eligible to garbage collection as there is no longer any reference to them. But eligible to garbage collection doesn't mean that they will be garbage collected immediately. Static methods or instance methods do not retain any references to local variables.

Answer (score 1):

After leaving the scope of your method `AMethod`, your `context` object can't be used anymore so it'll be garbage collected eventually.

But as it implements `IDisposable`, you should use the `using` statement:

```
using (ObjectContext context = new ...)
{
    // Use the context here
}
```